# clip 2 or more triangles with a circle using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, clipping

my question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22612323/clipping-a-triagle-with-a-circle-in-matplotlib)! but i want to use 1 circle to clip 2 triangles or more.

so i tried adding 2 triangles with `add_patch` but it throws syntax error:

```
patchpoly = ax.add_patch(polygon1, polygon2)
```

so i know i can't go this way.

here is the code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

polygon1 = plt.Polygon([(0,0.6),(1,2),(2,0.4)],color='g',alpha=0.25)
polygon2 = plt.Polygon([(0,0),(1,0.5),(0.5,1)],color='b',alpha=0.25)
circle = plt.Circle((0,0), 1.0, color='r', alpha=0.25)
patchpoly = ax.add_patch(polygon1)  # i know this line would be  meaningless
patchpoly = ax.add_patch(polygon2)

ax.add_patch(circle)
patchpoly.set_clip_path(circle)
```

and the result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/URQEt.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you're nearly there; just give the `polygon2` patch a unique name, i.e. `patchpoly2 = ax.add_patch(polygon2)` and then also instruct the patch to get 'clipped' at the end of the circle via `patchpoly2.set_clip_path(circle)`